# How do I tie VSCode update notification to apt update?

Tags: notifications, updates, visual-studio-code

There is a delay (multiple days) from when a VSCode update is available thru their website - thus showing me the update notification - and when it's available in the apt package distribution.

Is there a way to modify the behavior of the update notification to check `apt update` instead of the normal channel?

Reference link : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/FAQ#_how-do-i-opt-out-of-vs-code-autoupdates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible.

See this github issue : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/55027

Answer (score 0):

I have tried `apt update` and `apt install code` to update it, but it shows that vscode is already in its latest version, but vscode still prompts for update.

So, every time there's an update, I download the .deb file and do `apt install ./<filename>.deb` , this updates code and preserves the extensions.

Or its also available in snap store

`sudo snap install --classic code` # or `code-insiders`
Once installed, the Snap daemon will take care of automatically updating VS Code in the background. You will get an in-product update notification whenever a new update is available.

source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux